# multicheck combobox with lost focus when select item :/

Tags: c#, combobox

I try to use this example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/CheckComboBox.aspx to create multicheck combobox. Everything is all right, but when user select item in dropdown list it close and need another time click on it and select next item.

It is possible that when I fires onClick and dropdown show i t don't hide unless mouse lost focus on combobox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments on the page you linked to, someone posted previously (August 2007) this exact question - and someone else responded with this alternative implementation as the solution: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/checkedcombobox.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't see it ;/